# numerical integration of matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical, integral

I have to numerically evaluate, in Matlab, the integral of the product of two functions A(x,y) and B(x,y). These two functions are in 2-dimensional array form. The integral should read as following

[image: $ C(x,z)=\int_{a}^{b} dy' A(x,y')B(y',z) $]

I understand that the function such as "trapz" are for numerical integration of arrays of data, but I do not understand ho to adapt to my case.

thank you

Giuseppe

Comment: I mistyped: A and B are 2-dimensional arrays

Comment: I recommend working on it a bit yourself and asking a more specific question. Unless someone on here has solved the exact problem that you are asking, it's unlikely that the stackoverflow community will be able to help. trapz will probably work for you, so play around with it and see what you can come up with on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guide you I will build some (square) matrix functions

```
%// Problem size.
n = 3;
%// Auxiliary constant matrices.
D1 = rand(n, n);
D2 = rand(n, n);
D3 = rand(n, n);
D4 = rand(n, n);
%// Matrix functions and product.
A = @(x,y) x^2*D1.^2 + y*D2;
B = @(y,z) (log(y)+z)*D3.^3 - z*sin(D4);
P = @(x,y,z) A(x,y)*B(y,z);
```

In this way `P` is a function of three variables, now we will integrate it in y, when x and z are both 0.

```
a = 0;
b = 1;
integral(@(y) P(0,y,0), a, b, 'ArrayValued', true)
```

To generalize the solution to arbitrary domains we can build a new function in (x,z)

```
Int = @(x,z) integral(@(y) P(x,y,z), a, b, 'ArrayValued', true);
```

and define a mesh

```
x = linspace(-1, 1, 11);
z = linspace(-2, 2, 21);
[X, Z] = meshgrid(x, z);
```

Now we can evaluate the integral on the whole mesh.

```
C = arrayfun(Int, X(:), Z(:), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

In this way `C` will contain all the integrals, stored in a 1D array of cells.

As a check we can get the result at (x,z) = (0,0) by calling

```
C{sub2ind([11 21], 6, 11)}
```